Getting URL search parameter with CSR component on Next.JS v14 deployed on AWS Amplify
Recommended way is to useSearchParams ref
However, when doing npm run build it results in an error and failed build
Error occurred prerendering page "/mypage". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Locally it works fine with npm run dev
Unsuccessful attempts include trying to use:
useRouter, usePathname
keywords:
'use client'

After quite a few tries and errors the following worked for me:
const MyPage = (pageParams: any) => {
    const searchParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pageParams.searchParams));  

Hacky way of JSON de/serializing of searchParams was needed to get it to work on AWS Amplify; otherwise it would just be of Proxy(Object) type.
